# Access Front MySql Back Runtime Error 7878

Tags: runtime-error, ms-access-2010, subform

RunTime Error The Data has been changed.

I`m having a difficult time with one of my sub-forms. It used to work without complaints but I guess now it decided to be a little verbose. On this form I have a subform that has a variety of checkbox options. Whenever the user enters a checkbox option and then exits to the main form there is an On Exit Event which runs. It combines some textboxes from various forms and then puts that value in a textbox on the main form.

```
 var1 = [Form1]![Textbox].Value 
 var2 = [Form2]![Textbox].Value 
 var3 = [Form3]![Textbox].Value 

 Me.[TextBox].Value = var1 & var2 & var3
```

For some reason upon exiting the subform I am getting the Runtime error.

The pattern is not apparent.

1. I can navigate from the subform to the main form without making any changes in either without receiving an error message.
2. If I go into the subform, make a change, exit the subform, the textbox will be updated with no complaint, however if I go back into the subform, do not make a change and then go back to the main form, then I get the runtime error
3. similarly after making sure that behavior 1 is true I can go into the subform, change something come back out, but if I try to go back into the subform and make an additional change I will get a complaint. (I was able to fix this by making an on enter event refresh the subform)

I am unable to get the Runtime Error fixed though... :(

Comment: This error occurs when you are trying to change data in two places at the same time. It can be due to using the wrong events or using recordsets and forms to update data. You may be able to find where the problem is by adding a few Me.Dirty=False to force a save.

Comment: Well when I get the 7878 the debugger goes straight to the Me.[TextBox].Value =... line The dirty is only giving me the error that two people are editing the same record. If I press run after it identifies the problem area it continues it's execution. It isn't clear why it is stopping for a line yet playing it later. When it debugs does it change the status of the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that this is an issue for many people with no solution. Here was my work around.

From my observation the form that was having it's Textbox.value updated is somehow silently updated by either the on enter or on exit of it's subform so when the on exit action of updating that textbox occurs it complains that the main form was updated, thus leaving me to conclude that when that form is updated it is not shown to the user.

Thus, my work around is to requery the main form on the subform's exit in order to get that new data loaded and changed.

Caveat!! Requery will by default bring you back to the first record thus presenting the possibility of changing the textbox of the wrong record. Thus as part of the requerying process, if you choose this hack, you will have to bookmark the current open record, requery, and then fetch that record again. I used the code from this webpage in order to achieve the desired effect. Thus circumnavigating the 7878.

Requery and stay on record:
http://www.baldyweb.com/Requery.htm

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the correct one by clicking the checkmark on the left. I would also add a code snip showing what you did because that link you posted might die, the code with it.

Comment: @HackSlash Nice callback to what I was doing 9 years ago.